# Auto wiring classes present in external projects in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Hi I have two projects one is a rest module, which has the endpoints, `web.xml`, and the `dispathcer-servlet.xml`, I have another project which has the business logic and is added as a dependency to the REST module. When I am auto wiring a bean present in business project in rest module, I am getting  `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`. But the bean present in the rest module are autowired.

**BusinessModule**
com.test.service--packagename
BaseService.java

**RestModule**
com.test.controller --- packagename
BaseController.java

now i am autowiring BaseService.java in BaseController.java and in my dispatcher-servlet.xml if am mentioning the  it is autowiring the BaseService.java bean but 
it will not recognize the @RestController becasue for BaseController.java the base  package name is com.test --- how ever if i am giving

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:778)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 111 more
```

Comment: could you add the entire BeanCreationException please?

Comment: Hi GabLeg.. i have updated the stack trace and in the below thread i have mentioned both the controller and service classes as well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467716/component-scan-not-working-as-expected

Comment: do you have any implementation for your service ? if yes, is the implementation a Bean ? if no, you should add something like that : 
`@Bean
  public IBaseService getService() {
      return new ServiceImplementation();
  }`

in your Business config. Or if there is only one implementaion, you could use `@Service' above the class.

Comment: it worked thanks :-)... i had the implementation class but i haven't annotated it ..

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @GabLeg i am having an issue while trying to create the repository bean i have posted it in a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510436/unable-to-create-spring-data-jpa-repository-bean-getting-beancreationexception,any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

The Rest module can't see the Bean in the Business module, you will probably need to do something like this :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.something.business")
public class BusinessConfig {

}


@Configuration
@Import(BusinessConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.something.rest")
public class RestConfig {

}
```

Comment: Hi GabLeg.. thanks for answer.. in my case both have the same package name

Comment: Hi GabLeg.. thanks for answer.. in my case both have the same package name i am trying to auto wire my Service Interface which is in com.test.one.Service and my controller is in com.test.one.Controller so i am giving the base package component  scan as 'com.test.one ' . If i am giving it as com.test.one it is not autowiring but if i am giving it as com.test.one.Service it is auto wiring the service interface but when i am trying to hit the end point i am getting a 404 as the package in which the controller is there is not scanned

Comment: presently, the controller config has `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.one.Controller")` and the Service config has `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.one.Service")` ? and it's still not working ? Just to make sure I understand what you said.

Comment: Oh I think i understand what you meant, try this `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.one.Controller", "com.test.one.Service"})` . If that's not it, could you edit your question with your files structure please?

Comment: Hi GabLeg ... i have edited my question with the package structure