# Component Scan not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

I have two different applications one for Business and one for Rest. Both of them exist in one EAR. Rest is a war and business is a jar. I am using the business jar in Rest application.

In the business application i have annotated the Service Interface with @component annotation.

Business Module --
com.test.project.service -- package name
BaseService.java -- Interface which i am trying to autowire in my Rest Controller

REST Module
com.test.project.controller -- package name
BaseServiceController -- Controller Class where i am trying to auto wire BaseService.java

dispatcher-servlet.xml

To register my business and controller classes available in "com.test.project" package , i am mentioning the XML configuration as 
BUT the container is not able to auto wire BaseService.java in BaseServiceController.java, i am getting BeanCreationException

However if i am mentioning my base package name as "com.test.project.service" , BaseService.java is being auto wired into BaseServiceController.java, but if am trying to hit an endpoint in controller i am getting 404 as the controller is not registered in the container

below is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.project" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>


</beans>
```

Service

```
public interface IBaseService {

    public void postData(String request) throws CustomException;

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/baseRequest")
public class BaseServiceController{
    @Autowired
    private IBaseService baseService;
    //private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseServiceController.class);


    @RequestMapping(value = "/testRequest", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String invokeInfo() throws CustomException{


        return "Spring Test";
    }

}
```

Below is the exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:778)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 111 more
```

Comment: can you share your xml configurations?

Comment: Hi Amer.. i have added my dispatcher servlet.xml

Comment: please share your service and controller class

Comment: Hi Amer..I have updated the service and controller class

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class as below

IBaseServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class IBaseServiceImpl implements IBaseService {

//Implement defined methods in interface IBaseService

}
```